# C++ Erase vector element by value

Tags: c++, function, vector, compiler-errors, stl

I have a vector with Cards and **i need to find card and remove it**. I tryed the code below but I am getting error: *binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Card'*

The code makes sense to me. Could you give me some tips how to make it works? Thanks!

```
void Player::RemoveCardFromPackage(const Card& cardToBeRemoved)
{    
    std::vector<Card>::iterator position = std::find(CadrVector.begin(), CadrVector.end(), cardToBeRemoved);
    if (position != CadrVector.end())
    {
        CadrVector.erase(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says what's wrong. You need to provide a way to compare `Card`s for equality. You can either pass your own predicate to `find`, or you can provide an `operator==` function that will be used for comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `find_if` instead, with custom compare function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Card
{
    int c;
public:
    Card(int c): c(c) {}
    int GetC() const { return c; }
};

std::vector<Card> CardVector;

class Player 
{
public:
    void RemoveCardFromPackage(const Card& cardToBeRemoved);
};

void Player::RemoveCardFromPackage(const Card& cardToBeRemoved)
{

    auto found = std::find_if(CardVector.begin(), CardVector.end(), [&cardToBeRemoved](Card const &card) 
    {
        return cardToBeRemoved.GetC() == card.GetC();
    });

    if (found != CardVector.end())
    {
        CardVector.erase(found);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Player p;
    Card c1(1);
    CardVector.push_back(c1);
    Card c2(2);
    CardVector.push_back(c2);
    Card c3(3);
    CardVector.push_back(c3);

    std::cout << "Before:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CardVector.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "Card C: " << CardVector[i].GetC() << " ";

    p.RemoveCardFromPackage(c2);

    std::cout << "\n\nAfter:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < CardVector.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "Card C: " << CardVector[i].GetC() << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Before:
Card C: 1 Card C: 2 Card C: 3

After:
Card C: 1 Card C: 3
```

Comment: you can use the erase-remove idiom.
// removes all elements that matches cardToBeRemoved
 CardVector.erase(
  std::remove_if(CardVector.begin(), CardVector.end(),
   [&] (Card const& card)->bool {
    return cardToBeRemoved.GetC() == card.GetC();
   }
  )
  , CardVector.end()
 );

Comment: Yep, this is a nice one!

Answer (score 3):

How do you expect [`std::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) to know how to compare two elements of your custom type `CadrVector`? When two of these elements are considered equal and when not? You have to define that.

So either pass a comparator to the fourth argument of `std::find()`, or overload the `==` operator of your type.